# AnythingSlider is not working with jQuery v. 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anythingslider

I'm working on a Wordpress site that requires that I use jQuery v. 1.7.2. 
But when I activate the AnythingSlider plugin (yes, the plugin is fully updated), nothing is working - it is like this plugin and that version of jQuery is conflicting somehow.

Do you have any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: check your console for error

Comment: Uhmm.. There is not really any code to show you. All I've done is to integrate AnythingSlider into my Wordpress, and when it's activated my jQuery stops working.

I get this error when I check console: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object object] has no method 'anythingSlider'"

Comment: You better try to fix this 1.7.2 requirement. Anyway, it' strongly advised that you use the bundled WP version.

Answer (score 0):

How are you replacing the jQuery version? Some plugins require it to be loaded via wp_enque and won't run otherwise. Check this out for more: http://gomakethings.com/jquery-wordpress/

@brasofilo - there's absolutely nothing wrong with replacing the bundled jquery version with another. In fact, it's a common best practice to use a minimized and/or CDN hosted version.